# Return Twice from File Within a loop

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I'm trying to return a value from a file twice (the first value, then the second value) before completing the loop. It currently returns the first value from the file twice before repeating the loop.

I could save the information in separate files but I don't know how to pull the first value from each file before repeating the loop. Ideas?

This is my script:

```
Loop, read, C:\Users\Michael\Google Drive\AutoHotKey\Reference Files\item.txt
{
Loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%
    {
    sleep 1500
    send 1
    sleep 1500
    send {enter}
    send 52
    sleep 1500
    send {enter}
    send 4
    sleep 1500
    send {enter}
    sleep 1500
    Send %A_LoopField%
    sleep 1500
    send {enter}
    sleep 1500
    Send %A_LoopField%
}
```

}

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem. Provide details regarding input and output. What's the structure of the files you want to read? What do you want to extract? Post a representative *input -> output* example!

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the first value - when the loop reads the line, you've got `a_loopfield` - that's the value of the very first line in each file.

But you are only looking in *one* file!  That's why you only get one value.  If you want to loop through all the `.txt` files in that directory, you have to use a wildcard.

Here's a schematic for you (an idea; you'll have to tweak it):

```
Loop, read, C:\Users\Michael\Google Drive\AutoHotKey\Reference Files\*.txt  ;loop through all .txt files in this directory
{
    thisfile = %a_loopfield%
    Loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine, %A_Tab%  ;now parse the file that is being looped
        {
            msgbox The file is: %thisfile%`r and the first line is %a_loopfield%
            break  ;since we only want the *first* line, then don't read any more of this file
    }
}
```